# Make nginx process at most one concurrent connection per IP

Tags: nginx, limit

I'm trying to make nginx delay connections so that at most 1 is processes per IP at a time.

I'm able to achieve dropping excess requests with error 503 like this:

```
limit_zone addr $binary_remote_addr 10m;
limit_conn addr 1;
```

But I want to make excess processes wait until the previous one is completed instead. Is it possible?